# como usar un repositorio git dentro de mi proyecto angualar

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

presento el siguiente caso ...tengo un repositorio con los estylos (css) y necesito incorporarlo en mi proyecto angular. alguien sabe como lo puedo lograr... no encuntro en ningun lado como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: crea la carpeta css en la rais del public coloca alli tu css y llamalo desde las etiquetas header del index o donde este tu html.

Comment: Lo puedes meter como un [sub módulo de git](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/?zx=ugz9vwez849c#inbox), y no estoy seguro de si tienes que ignorar luego eso pero ya sería trabajo aparte, de este modo agregas esa "dependencia" sin perder carácteristicas como hacer un pull al repo de los estilos de CSS.